# Disabling browser refresh programmatically caused by addons or plugins

Tags: javascript, java, browser, cross-browser, firefox-addon

We are maintaining a website where based on user access of different webpages we keep alive a cookie and do a session timeout based on inactivity(based on the cookies access timestamp).

Recently we found out there are many browser plugins (e.g Reload Every for Firefox etc.) which can programmatically refresh a web page, defeating our purpose of properly calculating when we should timeout the user.

I have tried the `AddonManager` API(FF version 4) and `ExtensionManager`(FF 2 and 3), but really reluctant to do some browser specific codes to disable plugins/ addons.

Is there any elegant solution to handle these addons or the auto page refresh scenario?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `disable plugins/ addons` - pretty sure a web page can't screw with a persons free choice to install whatever plugins/addons they want to install

Comment: Thanks for your reply but we can't go to million machines and enforce disable relevant plugins.

Comment: Monitor keyboard and mouse activity.